# Can't connect to my React app from my mobile device

Tags: reactjs, networking, connection, wifi, ip-address

I am having some issues connecting to my React app running on my PC from my mobile device. I remember being able to do it awhile back, but for some reason it's not working anymore.

Both devices are on the same WiFi network. I have mesh routers and I verified they are connected to the same one (not sure if that matters). I'm running Windows 11 and trying to connect from an Android device.

I'm getting a connection timeout when trying to connect to my app from my phone (ip address below is fake):

```
This site can't be reached

192.559.2.27 took too long to respond

Try:
Checking the connection

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I verified that the ip address I'm trying to connect to is the correct one and I am attempting to connect to the right port. Any thoughts on what the issue might be or some settings I could check?

Comment: have you tried it from the PC?

Comment: @DanielFarrell Yes, the app opens from the PC when I go to localhost:3000 or 192.559.2.27:3000

Comment: Are you sure your phone is using the same network as your PC?

Comment: Check your windows firewall

Comment: @Vendetta both devices are connected to the same WiFi network. I tried turning off my data on the phone as well to be extra sure.

Comment: So if I set my WiFi network on my PC to a private network, I am able to connect. It's set to public by default and I can't connect when it's public. I'm not sure if this changed when I updated to Windows 11 or what, but not sure what the best course of action here is. Would it be okay to just set my WiFi network as private as long as I trust all of the devices that are connected to it? Or is there a way to create an allow list on the public network and add my phone as an allowed device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer here was to simply set my home WiFi network as a private network. Windows 11 sets the network type to "public" by default, which prevents it from being discovered by other devices on the network.

1. On Windows 11, go to Settings -> Network & Internet -> Wi-Fi ->  properties
2. Change the Network profile type to private

Obviously, you'll only want to do this on a trusted network and not a public Wi-Fi or anything.