# Can't open react app on mobile phone (TypeScript)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, vite, nodemon

I have problem to see my app on mobile Phone by hosting on localhost laptop after open  (addressip:3000) but that link work on another pc.

`"scripts": { "dev": "SET NODE_ENV=production & nodemon src/server/main.ts -w src/server", "start": "NODE_ENV=production ts-node src/server/main.ts", "build": "vite build" },`your text``

Comment: Which problem are you getting?  @Wujek Bobixon

Comment: @juanmajmjr After hosting the application, I can't display it on the phone when I enter the IP address, but it works fine on other computers, can it be changed somehow so that it hosts in the same way as npm start in React?

Comment: Are the mobile phone and the laptop connected to the same network? @Wujek Bobixon

Comment: Maybe this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73515261/cant-connect-to-my-react-app-from-my-mobile-device is similar or same than yours.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.